# Creating own beamer theme

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to create my own `beamer theme` and I've got the rough code for it.

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext,enumerate,charter}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,positioning,calc}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontseries{#2}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont}
\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{0,191,255}
%\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{226, 245, 13}
\definecolor{ora}{RGB}{253,111,1}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[inner color=blau] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
            \node[opacity=.6] at ([xshift=.05cm,yshift=1.03cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\Huge\sc Die Überschrift};
        \node[red] at ([yshift=1cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\Huge\sc Die Überschrift};
        \node[ora] at ([yshift=-.5cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south east)$) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{it}Der Autor};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill[path fading=north,fading transform={yshift=-.5cm},fading angle=225,blau] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
                \node[yshift=.2cm,above left] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
                \node[yshift=.15cm,xslant=.6,xshift=-1.75cm,yscale=-1,opacity=.4] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Zeichnen mit Ti\emph{\color{blau}k}Z};
                \fill[opacity=.6,black] ([xshift=2.1cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.6cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm]current page.north west);
            \fill[red] ([xshift=2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm]current page.north west);
            \node[white,inner sep=0pt] (a) at ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]current page.north west) {\changefont{pzc}{b}{n}Thema};
            \node[white,below=.2mm of a] {\changefont{lmtt}{m}{b}1};
            \draw[red,thick,yshift=.1cm] (-1,3) -- (7.7,3) node[near end,above,xshift=1cm,red] {\changefont{put}{m}{n}Der Titel};
%           \node[below left,opacity=.3,rotate=-20,xshift=1cm,yshift=-.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{shot}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-2cm}\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\color{black!85}\footnotesize\blindtext[1]}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
                \fill[path fading=north,fading transform={yshift=-.5cm},fading angle=225,blau] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
                    \node[yshift=.26cm,above left] at (current page.south east) {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Die Präsentation};
%                   {Das Arbeiten mit \color{blau}\sc\LaTeX};
                    \node[yshift=.15cm,xslant=.6,xshift=-1.6cm,yscale=-1,opacity=.4] at (current page.south east)  {\changefont{lmr}{m}{n}Die Präsentation};
%                   {Das Arbeiten mit \color{blau}\sc\LaTeX};
                    \fill[opacity=.6,black] ([xshift=2.1cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.6cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3.1cm]current page.north west);
                \fill[red] ([xshift=2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-1.2cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=3cm]current page.north west);
                \node[white,inner sep=0pt] (a) at ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]current page.north west) {\changefont{pzc}{b}{n}Thema};
                \node[white,below=.2mm of a] {\changefont{lmtt}{m}{b}2};
                %\node[below left,opacity=.3,rotate=-20,xshift=1cm,yshift=-.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{shot}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-2cm}\parbox{.7\textwidth}{
            \begin{enumerate}[\tikz{\fill[white]circle(.13);\fill[red]circle(.1);}]
                \item \color{black!85}Hallo,
                \item Welt!
            \end{enumerate}
            }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

My questions are: How can I achieve that

- In the bottom right corners appear the long `frame title`? ✔¹
- Instead of "Thema" there appears the short `frame title`?✔¹
- Instead of manually entering the `section` number there appears the "normal" number?
- The "shadow" effect (e.g. *Das Zeichnen mit TikZ*; the same text with lower opacity below) automaticly adjusts on the text above (in mean that there is no longer `xshift=…` needed)?

I know just some commands which changed this into a "theme", but I'm not experienced with the use of the `beamer` class, I just know the basics.

---

¹ Many Thanks to [`samcarter`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81896/discussion-on-question-by-current-user-creating-own-beamer-theme).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already using `tikz` you can use it to freely place the frametitle and subtitle.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \node[yshift=-0.4cm,xshift=1cm,anchor=west] at (current page.north west) {\insertframesubtitle}; 
        \node[yshift=0.4cm, anchor=east] at (current page.south east) {\insertframetitle};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle}
\framesubtitle{framesubtitle}
content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```